# UTF-8 characters display incorrectly

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a php file which uses a class file. Some of the utf-8 characters doesn't display correctly.
Instead if ת I get ú and many other mistakes, but not all. Most of the letters are displayed correctly.

Right now the php file is set to utf8, has the line `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
The class file is also saved in utf8 and has the line `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

When I change the class file to ANSI then some of the text suddenly work, while the others dont. (Not some characters, some text.) When I change it back to utf8 all the text works except for certain characters. (9 characters more or less)

I tried everything I could find...
The text that displays correctly when the class file is in ANSI originates from the php file, and the texts that display incorrectly originates in the class file.

Thank you!

Comment: See [utf-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), and use a program editor like [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org) that can switch encodings to test whether the source is in the correct encoding. Further mind the `u"..."`.

Comment: Also ensure that your webserver is set to use UTF-8 as it may be sending a header saying it is in a different charset

Comment: Post some actual code and/or URL. The description is far too vague for constructive analysis now.